# How to force a docker push on mac osx

Tags: macos, docker

EDIT
It seems that force is no longer needed.
/EDIT

On Linux I can force a docker version to the registry like this:
`docker push -f` This is needed if you push the same image version.

`docker tag -f <imagename> <registry>:"latest"
docker push -f <registry>:"latest"`

And all is well.

However when I try to do that on Mac OSX, I get the following error `unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f`
This is by using Docker Version 1.12.0-rc2-beta17 (build: 9779)

However if I don't use the -f option (under Linux) I get the following error:

`Error response from daemon: Conflict: Tag latest is already set to image 00e267155bd9e69ee1dbee623f63daeed93e303cc10f7a32cfdcc30c759046d5, if you want to replace it, please use -f option`

Does anybody know how to force a push and/or tag from OSX?

Comment: Linux 1.11.2 does not have the -f argument either. what version are you using?

Comment: On CentOS: Docker version 1.8.2-el7.centos     You mean to say that this option is removed?

Comment: Can't find any mention about it in the changelog. But it looks like it has been removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a Docker version >=1.12.0. Starting with version 1.12.0, the `-f` option is not available and not necessary anymore, since the image will always be replaced. This is the reason, why `-f` option is not described on the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/), but it is mentioned on the [Docker Deprecated Engine Features page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/) instead.